# Using Spring mvc with spring webflux without using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, webclient

So I have a old working  application which uses Spring MVC and not spring boot. I have added gradle dependency of spring-webflux in my project and start using webclient for calling external APIs from my project. This is my webclient handler class:

```
@Service
public class WebclientHandler {
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public WebclientHandler (WebClient.Builder builder) {
        this.webClient = builder.baseUrl("baseurl").build();
    }
}
```

Now I am getting this error after when I call this code through my API:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

It seems like my application is not able to find Webclient.builder and constructor injection does not occur. Is this because I am not using spring boot?

This is my Gradle dependency:

```
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webflux', version: '5.3.15')
```

I am new to spring-webflux reactive programming.

**EDIT**

I have tried to create Webclient bean using configuration also:

```
 @Configuration
    public class WebClientHandler {
    
    @Bean
        public WebClient myWebClient() {
            WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("baseUrl")
                    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .build();
            return client;
        }
}
```

Now I am getting this exception on startup:

```
{ java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default ClientHttpConnector found
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.initConnector(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:297)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.build(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:266)
    at com.kronos.orgmap.sbs.impl.service.WebClientHandler.MyWebClient(WebClientHandler.java:41)
    at com.kronos.orgmap.sbs.impl.service.WebClientHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59a9a582.CGLIB$desiWebClient$0(<generated>)
    at com.kronos.orgmap.sbs.impl.service.WebClientHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59a9a582$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$76fa510d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.kronos.orgmap.sbs.impl.service.WebClientHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59a9a582.MyWebClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosConstructorResolver.instantiate(KronosConstructorResolver.java:654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(KronosConstructorResolver.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:611)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(KronosAbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosAbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(KronosAbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosDefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(KronosDefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosAbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(KronosAbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosAbstractBeanFactory.getBean(KronosAbstractBeanFactory.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.KronosDefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(KronosDefaultListableBeanFactory.java:952)
    at com.kronos.container.impl.startup.KronosBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(KronosBeanFactory.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these dependencies in my gradle resolved the issue for me for 2nd approach, Now the DefaultWebClientBuilder is able to initiate connector to be used by webclient builder.

```
implementation platform('io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:2020.0.17')
    implementation 'io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core' 
    implementation 'io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http'
```

Although still didn't figured out why the first approach not working even after adding the mentioned gradle dependencies. Still not able to find WebClient.Builder class as bean in constructor.

Comment: reactor-netty-http os the reason it works

Answer (score 0):

You can only use 'spring-boot-starter-webflux':

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```